# “Back to” vs “Back in”?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning, difference, phrase-usage, prepositional-phrases

What is the difference between them when we use them in the following form:

> - This, my picture, is back **to** 1990.
> - This, my picture, is back **in** 1990.

[image: back in; back to]

Comment: More context please.  It's not clear what the picture actually *represents*.  If it's a picture of you *in* 1990 then that's the only preposition that works.  "Back to 1990" implies movement back in time, *"This story takes us back to 1990,  when I was still a young man"*

Comment: Neither of your examples sounds quite right. You might be trying to say "This is a picture of me back in 1990."

Comment: A personal picture, I pointed to it. Then, I would say, “this is back to/in 1990.” @Andrew

Comment: Is it due to “back” being an adverb so it’s impossible to fit into an adjective place? @ThePhoton

Comment: Could we, simultaneously, use “back to” as an alternative to “back in”? @ThePhoton

Comment: No, Michael J Fox can go back **to** the future, but you're photo shows you when you were already **in** the past.

Comment: Please stop trying out other ideas when you have been given the answer, @BavyanYaldo. It's not because it's an adverb, it's not because you can never say _back to 1990_, it's because _to_ always implies (actual or metaphorical) movement towards, so the expression _back to_ can only be used when there is (actual or metaphorical) movement expressed.

Comment: @BavyanYaldo You should incorporate the extra information you have provided in the comments into your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ngram is irrelevant, because it ignores context. As Andrew says in a comment, we use *back to 1990* only when there is a (metaphorical) notion of moving back in time.

So we can say *this picture goes back to 1990*, but if we are not using that metaphor, we have to say *in*: *this picture was in 1990* or *this picture was taken in 1990*, or *this picture is of me in 1990*, or *this is back in 1990*.

Comment: Or even nostalgia: *"Wow, this picture **takes me back to** 1990.  I still had hair!"*

Comment: So If  I am not **certain** when a picture was taken, do I have to use a metaphor usage “back to”?

Comment: @BavyanYaldo  *"I don't know **in** what year this picture was taken"*

Comment: Or in ordinary English _I don't know what year this picture was taken in_. Or _I don't know what year this picture is from_.

Comment: There is, also, “throwback to”, I t is the same, I think, as “back to” and it’s usage is nostalgic. @Andrew isn’t it?

Comment: @BavyanYaldo  as in *"Her clothes are a **throwback to** the 80s"*, yes